# Two Fields Either or Required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, I am trying to figure out how to make my email address or phone number field required but when either one is entered the other one is no longer required. Maybe my validation needs to be fixed to work better with the jQuery Validator? What makes this tough is the form is so complex. These are only required once shown (there not always shown) so once the radio button pops this form up then it needs to work where either or is required but the customer can still fill out both.

```js
 

    $(document).on('change', '#Email', function() {
 
 var value      = $(this).val();
 var EmailPhone = $('#EmailPhone');
  
 if (value == "" ) {
  EmailPhone.prop('required',true); 
    } else {
  EmailPhone.prop('required',false);
    }
});

$(document).on('change', '#EmailPhone', function() {
 
 var value      = $(this).val();
 var Email      = $('#Email');
  
 if (value == "" ) {
  Email.prop('required',true); 
    } else {
  Email.prop('required',false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix">
    <label for="EmailName">Your Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="EmailName" id="EmailName" value="" />
</div>
       
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="Email">Email:</label>
 <input type="Email" name="Email" id="Email" value="" />
</div>

<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="EmailPhone">Phone Number:</label>
 <input type="text" name="EmailPhone" id="EmailPhone" value="" />
</div>
        
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="EmailTitle">Title:</label>
 <input type="text" name="EmailTitle" id="EmailTitle" value="" />
</div>

<div class="clearfix">    
 <label for="EmailVin">VIN:</label>
 <input type="text" name="EmailVin" id="EmailVin" value="" />
</div>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated everything I have tried does not do what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: whats with the blank blocks if (
            }

        } else {
     
        }

    });

Comment: I think you are wanting: `'change', '#Email,#EmailPhone', function()`, otherwise your 3rd argument is going to be used as data and not as a selector, see the [function reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) for details

Comment: lol I duno iv just changed and tried my code about 20 different times and am getting no where... was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction

Comment: Its hard to supply an answer without seeing the rest of your code, but If you are making changes to the "required" attributes AFTER your validator has already attached itself to the form, then you would need to reset (rerun) or update the validator so that it can be made aware of the changes in your validation requirements.